# $http get request always returns 401 unauthorized - doesnt send auth header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, authentication, http-headers

im using the following controller in angularjs

```js
app.controller('download-posts-controller', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8090/posts', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJQYXNjYWwiLCJ1c2VySWQiOiIxMjMiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4ifQ.4D9TUDQAgIWAooyiMN1lV8Y5wVCrIF4rAeGzFzelSE9diqHMik9WE9x4EsNnEcxQXYATjxAZovpp-m72LpFADA'
        }
      }).success(function(response){
        window.alert(response)
    });
});
```

It should just call my API with a GET request, sending the authorization token in the header to validate the request at the server.

I receive a 401 unauthorized. My API layer has CORS enabled so that shouldn't be the issue.

In the browser inspection I see that it seems to be making a OPTIONS request anyway for some reason, and also doesn't send the auth token in the header.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?. 
I am very new to angularjs

Comment: Are you returning a `401` status code at any point in the API controller

Comment: Make sure your token is valid

Comment: yes, I do get a 401 at the server, the same token is definitely valid as its a non-expiring token i use for development and I can use it for the same request in postman or from my android app (or the apache wicket equivalent of my website as i only just migrated to angular) and it gives me the response i'd expect.

Comment: the only way i can get it to make the actual GET and not the unwanted OPTIONS request is to remove the header component from the request. I then tried an http interceptor to add the header and that doesnt work either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I eventually found that a cross origin (CORS) request first sends an OPTIONS request to ensure that the user request is permitted. 
Now...I have some logic in my api back-end that filters all incoming HTTP and checks for presence of Authorization header including a token (in all cases except when the uri contains '/auth/**'). When the initial OPTIONS request is performed, the token in auth header that i provided doesn't get included as the browser first waits until the OPTIONS come back to say that i can make this request......therefor an exception is thrown at the server because the OPTIONS request isn't validated with a token.

The fix...I simply put a check for "OPTIONS" HTTP method and ignore auth in this case. Simple. 
Thanks for anybodies help in trying to solve this. In the end it just required a lot of debugging.

I hope this may help to guide at least one other person who gets a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to set credentials mode:

```
app.controller('download-posts-controller', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8090/posts', {
        headers: {
            //USE credentials mode
            withCredentials: true,
            'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJQYXNjYWwiLCJ1c2VySWQiOiIxMjMiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4ifQ.4D9TUDQAgIWAooyiMN1lV8Y5wVCrIF4rAeGzFzelSE9diqHMik9WE9x4EsNnEcxQXYATjxAZovpp-m72LpFADA'
        }
      //SUCCESS is deprecated, removed from v1.6
      //}).success(function(response){
      }).then(function(response) {
        window.alert(response)
    });
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage).

---

> this looked promising, but it still returned 401 and the header was not present in the request according to my browser. it always says that the request method was OPTIONS too

The OPTIONS request from the browser is a [pre-flight request.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#Preflighted_requests_in_CORS)

In [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), a preflight request with the OPTIONS method is sent, so that the server can respond whether it is acceptable to send the request. The [Access-Control-Request-Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Method) header notifies the server as part of a preflight request that when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with the specified request method. The [Access-Control-Request-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers) header notifies the server that when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with the specified headers.  The server then has an opportunity to determine whether it wishes to accept a request under these circumstances.

The server responds with [Access-Control-Allow-Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) which specifies the viable methods to query the resource in question.

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents evil websites from using a user's location and credentials to do evilness. The [pre-flight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#Preflighted_requests_in_CORS) allow servers to give browsers permission to relax that policy when those requests would be harmless.

Comment: this looked promising, but it still returned 401 and the header was not present in the request according to my browser. it always says that the request method was OPTIONS too (even if i change the url to, say, stackoverflow. com - though i get 301 here instead). any ideas why?

Comment: ive just debugged the server to confirm that the header is never included in the request sent from angular page, but i make the same request by any other method and the header is included